# How do I create an action after a specific number of touches on a screen?

Tags: xcode, touch, save, screen

I am making an app that has to save the screen, like a screenshot, when the screen is tapped or touched a specific number of times. I have tried all of the solutions that other users have suggested that are associated with my question, but nothing helps...

I will appreciate all suggestions. :)
Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, are you are talking about multiple taps (i.e. double-tap, triple-tap, etc.) rather than multiple fingers touching the screen at once (i.e. two-finger tap, three-finger tap, etc.)?

Comment: I mean, for example, you tap the screen 10 time, and the screen saves

Comment: Then, unless you need to do very time-sensitive analysis of touch events with 1-9 taps, a `UITapGestureRecognizer` should work perfectly for you. See the article I linked to in my answer and the Apple documentation for that gesture recognizer. It has a method that lets you set the number of taps it is triggered after.

Comment: what is this event called: the event described by a finger on the screen until it comes off, like for example in a drawing app?
Is there one name for everything that the finger does on the screen (taps, touches, swipes etc.)?

Comment: A `tap` is the user touching the screen and then removing their finger without moving it. A `touch` is one finger on the screen, so if you set the number of touches required by a tap gesture recognizer to 2, you are saying the user must have two fingers on the screen at the same time. A `swipe` is when the user places one or more fingers on the screen and moves it before lifting their finger again.

Comment: If you want to know that the user pressed their fingers down and did not move them for a certain length of time, that is a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. If you want to know that the user pressed down, moved a certain amount, and then lifted, that is a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. You can also create custom gesture recognizers that recognize a certain pattern the fingers move in (for example, a check mark swipe). Look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more on these topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following blog post does a good job of explaining the built-in option for recognizing multiple taps in a row (and explains the shortcomings): [Detecting tap and double-tap with Gesture Recognizers](http://iphonedevsphere.blogspot.com/2010/09/detecting-tap-and-double-tap-with.html).

If you need more customized logic than is provided by the built-in gesture recognizers, you will either be implementing your own custom subclass of `UIGestureRecognizer` or you will be adding your logic into the `UIResponder` (superclass of `UIViewController`, `UIView`, etc.) callbacks for tap input: `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, `touchesMoved:withEvent:`, and `touchesEnded:withEvent:`.

I have more experience with the latter method (not `UIGestureRecognizer`). The `UITouch` events passed to the various `UIResponder` callbacks each contain information about touch location and touch timing. You could use this information in combination with a `NSTimer` to determine if the user taps twice (or more) within a certain amount of time. If the timer fires before the second (or `n`th touch), then you can consider it a single touch event.

I don't know if that is the best way to do this, but it is certainly more granular control than the built-in `UIGestureRecognizer`s provide you.